# How to parameterize complex OleDB queries?

Tags: c#, sql, oledb, sql-injection

I'm trying to refactor some code that is using strings concatenation for creating SQL commands (which makes it vulnerable for a SQL injection). Basically all I'm trying to do is to replace all the `string sqlToExecute = String.Format(..)` statements with a SQL command and a List of OleDB parameters.

I understand how this can be done for simple cases like `String.Format("Select * from myTable where id = {0}", id)`. However, I could not find a set of good examples for more complex SQL queries.

Here are some of the queries that I'm not sure how exactly I can parameterize:

**1. Parameters are used for both column name and alias; Parameter consists of two variables:**

```
    selQueryBldr.AppendFormat("SELECT * FROM {0} {1} 
    INNER JOIN ColChange CC ON CC.TableRecordID = {1}.{2} and CC.EntityID='{3}'",
    entity.StageTableName, stageTableAlias, entity.PrimaryKey, entity.EntityID);
```

**2. Same parameter is used in multiple SQL IN clauses**

SQL Query:

```
      SELECT A.TablePrefix ...
      FROM Entity E
      INNER JOIN App A
      ON A.AppID = E.AppID
      WHERE E.AppID in (#APPIDS#)

      UNION

      SELECT A.TablePrefix ...
      FROM EntityB EB
      INNER JOIN App A
      ON A.AppID = EB.AppID
      WHERE EB.AppID in (#APPIDS#)
```

Currently the parameter is added in the code by using String.Replace() method:

```
    sqlQuery = sqlQuery.Replace("#APPIDS#",idList);
```

**3. Using variables as a parameter name and a parameter value:**

```
    StringBuilder dataQuery = new StringBuilder("Select * from {0} WHERE {1}='{2}'",
    tableName, primaryKey[0], changeRow["TableRecordID"]);
```

**4. Variable used a part of the unicode parameter:**

```
    sSQL = string.Format("SELECT name FROM sysobjects WHERE id = object_id(N'[dbo].[{0}]')",
    sSPName);
```

Also, all of these examples are using OleDb classes (OleDbConnection/OleDbCommand etc.), thus as far as I understand named parameters can not be used here.

Comment: Looks like the scenario #2 can work if I pass all parameters for the IN clause individauly e.g.: `... WHERE EB.AppID in (?, ?, ?)`

Answer (score 1):

Different back-ends allow (or not) either named parameters, or "?" place-holders for parameters, so what you would do is build your query something like

```
OleDbCommand oCmd = new OleDbCommand( YourConnection, "select * from someTable where yourColumn = ? and otherColumn = ?" );

oCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue( "parm1", YourVariable.FormattedHoweverNeeded );
oCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue( "parm2", anotherVariable.FormattedHoweverNeeded );
```

If the columns are expecting strings, ensure a string.  If expecting numeric (int, double, float, etc), leave as that type too, or other (date/time, etc)

Just note... if not doing named parameters (as I have with "?" place-holder), the parameters must be added in the same sequence as the "?" are placed in the SQL command.

Comment: DRapp, thanks, but as I mentioned in my question the case when I need to parameterize SQL parameters is the simplest. My question was about the cases when I need to parameterize other parts of the SQL query - column/table names, aliases etc.